# C program for printing function details of a C file

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, structure, coredump

For a given C code, I'd like to print the function name and the number of lines for every function.

Below is my code:

```
struct fundetails
{
    int nooflines;
    char funcname[SIZE];
}s[SIZE];


char *ffname(char *line,char *name)
{

    int i=1,j=0;
    char *dt; 

    strtok(line,"("); 
    dt = strchr(line,' '); 
    if(dt[i] == '*')
        i++;
    while(dt[i] != '\0')
    {
        name[j]=dt[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    name[j] ='\0';
    return NULL;  //...
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Give the filename \n");
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    int i, lines =0, funlines =0,count =0, fn =0, flag =0, fg=0,size=0,emptyflag=0,commandflag=0;
    char c[SIZE],b[SIZE],st[SIZE],d[SIZE];
    char *fname;
    int command[]={};
    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(c,SIZE,fd))
    {
        emptyflag=0;    
        lines++;
        for(i=0;i<(sizeof(command)/4);i++)
        {
            if(lines == command[i])
            {
                commandflag=1;
                break;
            }   
        }
        strcpy(st,c);
        strtok(st," ");
        size = strlen(c);
        if(size == 1 && (strcmp(c,"\n"))== 0)// Checking for empty line
            emptyflag=1;
        if( !strcmp(st,"struct")) // Checking whether line is structure or struct function
            fg=1;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(commandflag)
            {
                break;
            }   
            while( c[i] =='\t' || c[i] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
            }
            if( c[i] == '{')
            {
                count++;
                if(flag)
                {
                    if(!emptyflag)
                        funlines++;
                    else
                        emptyflag=0;
                }
                if(count ==1 && fg ==1)
                {
                    if(b[strlen(b)-2] == ')')
                    {
                        fn++;
                        printf("Dhahira");
                        printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn); 

                        flag = 1;
                        printf("Dhahira");
                        ffname(b,fname);
                        printf("Function name is:%s\n",fname);
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        count--;
                    }   
                }
                else if(count == 1)
                {
                    fn++;
                    printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn); 
                    flag = 1;
                    ffname(b,fname);//...
                    printf("Function name is:%s\n",fname);
                }
                break;
            }
            else if( c[i] == '}')
            {
                count--;
                if(count ==0 && fg ==1)
                { 
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("No of lines in the function %d is: %d\n", fn, funlines);
                    printf("Function %d is finished..........\n", fn);
                    s[fn-1].nooflines=funlines;//...
                    strcpy(s[fn-1].funcname,fname);//..
                    funlines = 0;
                    fg=0;
                }
                else if(count ==0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("No of lines in the function %d is: %d\n", fn, funlines);
                    printf("Function %d is finished..........\n", fn);
                    s[fn-1].nooflines=funlines;//...
                    strcpy(s[fn-1].funcname,fname);//..
                    funlines = 0;
                }
                else if(count == -1)
                {
                    count=0;
                    fg=0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(!emptyflag)
                        funlines++;
                    else
                        emptyflag=0;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(flag ==1 && fg==1)
            {
                if(!emptyflag)
                    funlines++;
                else
                    emptyflag=0;
                break;
            }
            else if(flag)
            {
                if(!emptyflag)
                    funlines++;
                else
                    emptyflag=0;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(commandflag == 1)
            commandflag = 0;
        else
            strcpy(b,c);
    }

    printf("FUN_NAME\tNO_OF_LINES\n");
    for(i=0;i<fn;i++)
    {
    printf("%s\t\t%d\n",s[i].funcname,s[i].nooflines);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output.

```
Function 1 is Started..............
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I thought that the`ffname` function might be a reason. But, when I included a printf statement above the line `printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn);`, still it doesn't print the line. So, I couldn't figure out the actual reason behind this issue. Kindly guide me to solve this.

Comment: you need to learn how to use a debugger.  Soon!

Comment: And you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, improve your code till no warnings are given, and learn to use `gdb` and `valgrind` to debug it; in your code `fname` seems to never be properly initialized.

Answer (score 4):

The segmentation fault is due to uninitialized use of `fname`. Declare it as an array:

```
char fname[256]; // or dynamically allocate
```

and it should work. You do not see the printf output because this function writes into a buffer and does not immediately output what you write. After the segmentation fault the buffered output is gone. You can force immediate output by using `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf`.

Also you can see a warning message if you compile your code with `-Wall` flag.